# oracle procedure with case It depends from parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I want to make a procedure like following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SOL.INSERT_LD_NEXTPROCESS (vgroupid NUMBER)
IS
VPERIODID     VARCHAR2 (10);
vPROCSESSID   NUMBER;

CURSOR c
IS
  SELECT COMPANYID,
         GROUPID,
         PERIODID,
         FN_PPROCESSCURRENT
FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
   WHERE     PROCESSID = FN_PPROCESSPREVIOUS
         AND (UNCOLLECTED > 0 OR INVOICE = 0)
```

I want to add an extra filter it depends from parameter:

```
CASE WHEN vgroupid > -1 then 
        AND GROUPID = vgroupid
ELSE
        NULL
END
...
```

so the where cause like

```
WHERE PROCESSID = FN_PPROCESSPREVIOUS
AND (UNCOLLECTED > 0 OR INVOICE = 0) AND GROUPID = vgroupid
```

when vgroupid = -1 then I need all records an when vgroupid > -1 then I need only the records in vgroupid

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CURSOR c
IS
  SELECT COMPANYID,
         GROUPID,
         PERIODID,
         FN_PPROCESSCURRENT
FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS
   WHERE     PROCESSID = FN_PPROCESSPREVIOUS
         AND (UNCOLLECTED > 0 OR INVOICE = 0)
         AND (((GROUPID = vgroupid) AND (vgroupid > -1)) OR (vgroupid = -1))
```

for example:
if `vgroupid = -1`, then last condition will be `(((GROUPID = -1) AND (-1 > -1)) OR (-1 = -1))` or `((forever_false AND forever_false) OR (forever_true))` or `(-1 = -1)` - all records

instead, if `vgroupid = 123` last condition will be `(((GROUPID = 123) AND (123 > -1)) OR (123 = -1))` or  `(((GROUPID = 123) and forever_true) OR (forever_false))` or `(GROUPID = 123)` - only 123 GROUPID

Comment: Stawros when the vgroupid = -1 then I need all records

Comment: @Giorgos without `(PROCESSID = FN_PPROCESSPREVIOUS) and (UNCOLLECTED > 0 OR INVOICE = 0)` conditions?

Comment: no, with contitions. When vgroupid = -1 then the contition is   PROCESSID = FN_PPROCESSPREVIOUS  AND (UNCOLLECTED > 0 OR INVOICE = 0) when the vgroupid = 242 the contition is PROCESSID = FN_PPROCESSPREVIOUS  AND (UNCOLLECTED > 0 OR INVOICE = 0) and GROUPID = vgroupid.

Comment: @Giorgos My query works the same. [GROUPID = vgroupid when vgroupid > -1, if vgroupid = -1 then no filter by GROUPID] are equal to [(((GROUPID = vgroupid) AND (vgroupid > -1)) OR (vgroupid = -1))]